# Protractor - "More than one element found for locator" when using by.id

Tags: vue.js, protractor

We are using by.id to reference an element but Protractor is still throwing this message "more than one element found for locator By(css selector, *[id="txt1"])" and it is returning the value of a label when getText() is used. The behaviour seems strange. When we refer to that element from Javascript, the reference seems fine. Appreciate your help in resolving this.

```
//Code in Protractor, it seems to be referring to a label
var txtEl=element(by.id('txt1'));

//Code in VueJS, where the ID is set to each InputText
                   //This is the label
                    <label class="form__label" v-model="form.label" v-show="form.hasOwnProperty('label')">
                        {{ index }}. {{ form.label }}
                    </label>

        <el-input type="text"
                  :id="currentField.id"
                  :placeholder="currentField.isPlaceholderVisible ? currentField.placeholder : ''"
                  v-model="currentField.value">
        </el-input>

//Code in Javascript, works fine, shows the right value
console.log("Value:" + this.$refs.form1["txt1"].value);
```

Comment: It seems the rendered page somehow got duplicated ids. Try to make a screenshot of the rendered page and see if the page looks correctly when running the test.

Comment: That is the strange part, the page looks correct and when we print the value using console.log (you can see that line), the right value is getting printed.

Comment: Added the VueJS code. Protractor is returning the value of a Label, not even an InputText. That is strange.

Comment: Are you sure the label doesn't also have `id="txt1"`? If you change it to `element.all(by.id('txt1'))`, how many elements are returned?

Comment: I have added the code for label to my question. As you can see, the ID is not set for the label and the value "currentfield:id" is asisgned only to id of <el-input>.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the source code at this time and you will fine out how many elements are in DOM with similar id

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
element(by.css('input[type = "text"]'))
```

Comment: But what we need to validate is the text entered. So this approach might not help. Is there a way I can specify the field type AND the id ?

Comment: Updated answer try the above.

Comment: Will this still work if I have 3 input text on that page and I need to validate the text from just one ? How do I use this in conjunction with the ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer after frustrating 10 hours of digging through.

1. Set ":name" for . Don't set ":id". Like this :name="currentField.id"
2. In Protractor code, use the name to fetch the element. Like this -
   var inputtxt=element(by.css("input[name='txt1']"));
3. Don't use getText(), it behaves weird, return empty. Use inputtxt.getAttribute('value')) where "value" is the underlying field assigned to "v-model"
4. IMPORTANT - allow the page to load fully by setting browser.sleep(x ms). Else the element gets retrieved multiple times, protractor throws a warning "More than one element is located...."